# Run Emacs as a daemon and then the emacs binary

Tags: emacs

On  a Mac OS,  I am able to run Emacs as a daemon and then the emacs binary. But, according to "Mastering Emacs" of Mickey Peterson (see the quote below), I should not be able to do that. Where do I misunderstand the book?

> emacs --daemon will run Emacs as a daemon. It will call server-start,
>   as above, but will return control to your terminal immediately and run in the background, waiting for client
>   requests.
>
> If you go the server route, you cannot use the default emacs binary
>   any more.

On a Mac Os, I launch Emacs with "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is misleading.  After you have started a server you can happily run either `emacs` or `emacsclient` as you wish.  The latter will connect to your server; the former will (as usual) start a new separate instance of Emacs.